# How to disable Tensorflow js error log for my server host?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

As if right now I am in a bit of a rush to get an answer to my problem. The model has been trained and the server works locally with the NN running in the background, but on the server we get the following error message:

> 2020-04-08 11:54:15.787274: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2799865000 Hz
>   2020-04-08 11:54:15.787801: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x4b5ca00 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
>   2020-04-08 11:54:15.787830: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>     what():  Resource temporarily unavailable

It seems that the server host doesn't like the fact that Tensorflow is trying to log the following error/warning message:

> 2020-04-08 11:53:42.453164: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to 
>   use: AVX2

Is there a way in JS to disable these error logs so we can run the trained model on the server? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to rebuild libtensorflow binaries. https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-node/pull/237/files#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8

Comment: Hi @Revess,  Are you using nodejs as your server?

Comment: @TF_Support yes we are using nodejs as the server. Our socket connection is managed via socket.io. No matter what I do I am unable to turn off this warning flag. Changing the enviroment variable, running node with the --no-warnings flag it is not working...